# loop to calculate timestamps

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a String input for timestamp like this:

```
23 46 22
```

where '23' denoted Hour of the day, '46' is the minute and '22' is the second.

I have a trivial problem. I need to get all the timestamps from this instance till the end of the day, i.e. from `23 46 22` to `23 59 59`

The loop that I am using to get all the timestamps (one at a time) is:

```
for (int i = hour; i < 24; i++) {
    for (int j = minute; j < 60; j++) {
        for (int k = second; k < 60; k++) {

        }
    } 
}
```

But this loop has a problem. The second counter will always start from the current second only, e.g.:

```
23 46 22
23 46 23.....
..
23 47 22
23 47 23...
```

I want to get timestamps in correct manner, e.g.:

```
23 46 22
23 46 23.....
..
23 47 01
23 47 02...
```

What is the elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the seconds and minutes at the end of each loop :

```
int m = minute;
int s = second;

for (int i = hour; i < 24; i++) {
    for (int j = m; j < 60; j++) {
        for (int k = s; k < 60; k++) {
            ....
        }
        s = 0;
    }
    m = 0;  
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that single digit numbers will not show a leading zero unless you format the output.  If this is for displaying to the console, you can add this line `System.out.printf("%02d %02d %02d %n", hour, m, s);` to the inner loop. If it is to save to a file, you can use `String.format("%02d %02d %02d %n", hour, m, s)`.